# Removable singularities for Dirichlet problems of Laplace equaions?

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

It is already known that if $u$ is harmonic in $\Omega\backslash\{x_0\}$ where $\Omega$ is a pre-compact domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $n\geq2$ and $u=o(|x-x_0|^{2-n})$ when $x\to x_0$, then the singular point $x_0$ is removable. i.e. $\exists\,\tilde{u}$ harmonic on $\Omega$ such that $\tilde{u}=u$ on $\Omega\backslash\{x_0\}$.

Now I came across a similar but more difficult case. I need to show that the following Dirichlet problem:
$$
\Delta u=0\,\,\,\text{in}\,\,\,\Omega\backslash\{x_0\}\\
u|_{\partial\Omega}=f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})\\
u\in L^{\infty}(\Omega\backslash\{x_0\})
$$

Obviously $f$ does not satisfy the requirements for removable singularities any more. Is it still true that this u coincide with solution of the same Dirichlet problem for Laplace equations on $\Omega$? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can there even be a singularity if $u\in L^\infty$ is harmonic? It is a bounded, continuous function and therefore can do no harm at $x_0$...

Comment: @uvs That's what I was unclear about... $u$ is merely harmonic and bounded in the punctured domain. Is it possible for $u$ to blow up at $x_0$?

Comment: Nope. If a continuous function blows up at a point, it must be unbounded in the punctured domain and hence cannot be $L^\infty$.